# More issues with pool allocator with free list

Tags: c++11, memory-management, initialization

In std::map, this ends up causing an error when the first object is constructed.  I've checked the debugger, and I see that **free_list::init()** creates the consecutive memory addresses correctly.  I'm aware this allocator cannot be used in vector or other related containers, but it's only meant to work with the nodular containers.

I get a run-time error from this in xutility (in VC12), at line 158:

```
_Container_proxy *_Parent_proxy = _Parent->_Myproxy;
```

Checking the debugger, it appears that **_Parent** was never initialized, bringing about the 0xC0000005 run-time error.  Why or how it didn't get initialized and why this occurred when the first object was being constructed (after **std::map** did 3 separate allocations), I do not know.

I would like to have this work with std::map and std::list and the other nodular containers and am not worried about whether it can perform in std::vector, etc.

```
#include <algorithm>

class free_list {
public:
    free_list() {}

    free_list(free_list&& other)
        : m_next(other.m_next) {
        other.m_next = nullptr;
    }

    free_list(void* data, std::size_t num_elements, std::size_t element_size) {
        init(data, num_elements, element_size);
    }

    free_list& operator=(free_list&& other) {
        m_next = other.m_next;
        other.m_next = nullptr;
    }

    void init(void* data, std::size_t num_elements, std::size_t element_size) {
        union building {
            void* as_void;
            char* as_char;
            free_list* as_self;
        };

        building b;

        b.as_void = data;
        m_next = b.as_self;
        b.as_char += element_size;

        free_list* runner = m_next;
        for (std::size_t s = 1; s < num_elements; ++s) {
            runner->m_next = b.as_self;
            runner = runner->m_next;
            b.as_char += element_size;
        }
        runner->m_next = nullptr;
    }

    free_list* obtain() {
        if (m_next == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        free_list* head = m_next;
        m_next = head->m_next;
        return head;
    }

    void give_back(free_list* ptr) {
        ptr->m_next = m_next;
        m_next = ptr;
    }

    free_list* m_next;

};

template<class T>
class pool_alloc {
    typedef pool_alloc<T> myt;

public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;

    typedef std::false_type propagate_on_container_copy_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_move_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_swap;

    template<class U> struct rebind {
        typedef pool_alloc<U> other;
    };

    ~pool_alloc() {
        destroy();
    }
    pool_alloc() : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(4096) {
    }
    pool_alloc(size_type capacity) : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(capacity) {}

    pool_alloc(const myt& other)
        : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(other.capacity) {}

    pool_alloc(myt&& other)
        : data(other.data), fl(std::move(other.fl)), capacity(other.capacity) {
        other.data = nullptr;
    }

    template<class U>
    pool_alloc(const pool_alloc<U>& other) 
        : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(other.max_size()) {}

    myt& operator=(const myt& other) {
        destroy();
        capacity = other.capacity;
    }

    myt& operator=(myt&& other) {
        destroy();
        data = other.data;
        other.data = nullptr;
        capacity = other.capacity;
        fl = std::move(other.fl);
    }

    static pointer address(reference ref) {
        return &ref;
    }

    static const_pointer address(const_reference ref) {
        return &ref;
    }

    size_type max_size() const {
        return capacity;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type) {
        if (data == nullptr) create();
        return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(fl.obtain());
    }

    void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type) {
        fl.give_back(reinterpret_cast<free_list*>(ptr));
    }

    template<class... Args>
    static void construct(pointer ptr, Args&&... args) {
        ::new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    static void destroy(pointer ptr) {
        ptr->~T();
    }

    bool operator==(const myt& other) const {
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>(data) ==
            reinterpret_cast<char*>(other.data);
    }

    bool operator!=(const myt& other) const {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

private:

    void create() {
        data = ::operator new(capacity * sizeof(value_type));
        fl.init(data, capacity, sizeof(value_type));
    }

    void destroy() {
        ::operator delete(data);
        data = nullptr;
    }

    void* data;
    free_list fl;
    size_type capacity;

};

template<>
class pool_alloc < void > {
public:
    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef pool_alloc<U> other; };

    typedef void* pointer;
    typedef const void* const_pointer;
    typedef void value_type;
};
```

The problem comes when std::pair is being constructed (in MSVC12 utility at line 214):

```
    template<class _Other1,
        class _Other2,
        class = typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Other1, _Ty1>::value
            && is_convertible<_Other2, _Ty2>::value,
            void>::type>
        pair(_Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&& _Val2)
            _NOEXCEPT_OP((is_nothrow_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1&&>::value
                && is_nothrow_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2&&>::value))
        : first(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1)),
                second(_STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2))
        {   // construct from moved values
        }
```

Even after stepping in, the run-time error occurs, the same as described above with _Parent not being initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question through extensive debugging.  Apparently, VC12's **std::map** implementation at least at times will cast an **_Alnod** (permanent allocator that stays in scope for the life of the **map**, which is used to allocate and deallocate the nodes in the **map**, what I'd expect to be what actually calls **allocate()** and **deallocate()**) as an **_Alproxy**, a temporary allocator which creates some sort of object called **_Mproxy** (or something like that) using **allocate()**.  The problem, though, is that VC12's implementation then lets **_Alproxy** go out of scope while still expecting the pointer to the allocated object to remain valid, so it is clear then that I would have to use **::operator new** and **::operator delete** on an object like **_Mproxy**: using a memory pool that then goes out of scope while a pointer to a location in it remains is what causes the crash.

I came up with what I suppose could be called a dirty trick, a test that is performed when copy-constructing or copy-assigning an allocator to another allocator type:

```
template<class U>
pool_alloc(const pool_alloc<U>& other)
    : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(other.max_size()), use_data(true) {
    if (sizeof(T) < sizeof(U)) use_data = false;
}
```

I added the **bool** member **use_data** to the allocator class, which if **true** means to use the memory pool and which if **false** means to use **::operator new** and **::operator delete**.  By default, it is **true**.  The question of its value arises when the allocator gets cast as another allocator type whose template parameter's size is smaller than that of the source allocator; in that case, **use_data** is set to **false**.  Because this **_Mproxy** object or whatever it's called is rather small, this fix seems to work, even when using **std::set** with **char** as the element type.

I've tested this using **std::set** with type **char** in both VC12 and GCC 4.8.1 in 32-bit and have found that in both cases it works.  When allocating and deallocating the nodes in both cases, the memory pool is used.

Here is the full source code:

```
#include <algorithm>

class free_list {
public:

    free_list() {}

    free_list(free_list&& other)
        : m_next(other.m_next) {
        other.m_next = nullptr;
    }

    free_list(void* data, std::size_t num_elements, std::size_t element_size) {
        init(data, num_elements, element_size);
    }

    free_list& operator=(free_list&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            m_next = other.m_next;
            other.m_next = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void init(void* data, std::size_t num_elements, std::size_t element_size) {
        union building {
            void* as_void;
            char* as_char;
            free_list* as_self;
        };

        building b;

        b.as_void = data;
        m_next = b.as_self;
        b.as_char += element_size;

        free_list* runner = m_next;
        for (std::size_t s = 1; s < num_elements; ++s) {
            runner->m_next = b.as_self;
            runner = runner->m_next;
            b.as_char += element_size;
        }
        runner->m_next = nullptr;
    }

    free_list* obtain() {
        if (m_next == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        free_list* head = m_next;
        m_next = head->m_next;
        return head;
    }

    void give_back(free_list* ptr) {
        ptr->m_next = m_next;
        m_next = ptr;
    }

    free_list* m_next;

};

template<class T>
class pool_alloc {
    typedef pool_alloc<T> myt;

public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;

    typedef std::false_type propagate_on_container_copy_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_move_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_swap;

    myt select_on_container_copy_construction() const {
        return *this;
    }

    template<class U> struct rebind {
        typedef pool_alloc<U> other;
    };

    ~pool_alloc() {
        clear();
    }
    pool_alloc() : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(4096), use_data(true) {}

    pool_alloc(size_type capacity) : data(nullptr), fl(), 
        capacity(capacity), use_data(true) {}

    pool_alloc(const myt& other)
        : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(other.capacity), 
            use_data(other.use_data) {}

    pool_alloc(myt&& other)
        : data(other.data), fl(std::move(other.fl)), capacity(other.capacity),
            use_data(other.use_data) {
        other.data = nullptr;
    }

    template<class U>
    pool_alloc(const pool_alloc<U>& other) 
        : data(nullptr), fl(), capacity(other.max_size()), use_data(true) {
        if (sizeof(T) < sizeof(U)) use_data = false;
    }


    myt& operator=(const myt& other) {
        if (*this != other) {
            clear();
            capacity = other.capacity;
            use_data = other.use_data;
        }
    }

    myt& operator=(myt&& other) {
        if (*this != other) {
            clear();
            data = other.data;
            other.data = nullptr;
            capacity = other.capacity;
            use_data = other.use_data;
            fl = std::move(other.fl);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<class U>
    myt& operator=(const pool_alloc<U>& other) {
        if (this != reinterpret_cast<myt*>(&other)) {
            capacity = other.max_size();
            if (sizeof(T) < sizeof(U))
                use_data = false;
            else
                use_data = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    static pointer address(reference ref) {
        return &ref;
    }

    static const_pointer address(const_reference ref) {
        return &ref;
    }

    size_type max_size() const {
        return capacity;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type) {
        if (use_data) {
            if (data == nullptr) create();
            return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(fl.obtain());
        } else {
            return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(::operator new(sizeof(T)));
        }
    }

    void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type) {
        if (use_data) {
            fl.give_back(reinterpret_cast<free_list*>(ptr));
        } else {
            ::operator delete(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr));
        }
    }

    template<class... Args>
    static void construct(pointer ptr, Args&&... args) {
        ::new ((void*)ptr) value_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    static void destroy(pointer ptr) {
        ptr->~value_type();
    }

    bool operator==(const myt& other) const {
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>(data) ==
            reinterpret_cast<char*>(other.data);
    }

    bool operator!=(const myt& other) const {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

private:

    void create() {
        size_type size = sizeof(value_type) < sizeof(free_list*) ? 
            sizeof(free_list*) : sizeof(value_type);
        data = ::operator new(capacity * size);
        fl.init(data, capacity, size);
    }

    void clear() {
        ::operator delete(data);
        data = nullptr;
    }

    void* data;
    free_list fl;
    size_type capacity;
    bool use_data;
};

template<>
class pool_alloc < void > {
public:
    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef pool_alloc<U> other; };

    typedef void* pointer;
    typedef const void* const_pointer;
    typedef void value_type;
};

template<class Container, class Alloc>
void change_capacity(Container& c, typename Alloc::size_type new_capacity) {
    Container temp(c, Alloc(new_capacity));
    c = std::move(temp);
}
```

Since the allocator is not automatic-growing (don't know how to make such a thing), I have added the **change_capacity()** function.